# Printing odd lines - line counter incremented two times

Tags: java, file, printing

i made a simple program, that i would like to print all odd lines from a file.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(file);
    int lineCount = 0; 
    int i = 0;

    while(fileRead.hasNextLine()){
      lineCount++;
      i = lineCount % 2;
      System.out.println("Line count -- >> " + lineCount);
      if(i == 1){
          System.out.println(fileRead.nextLine());
      }          
    }        
    fileRead.close();
 }
}
```

So when i run it, the output is

Line count -- >> 1

odd

Line count -- >> 2

Line count -- >> 3

even

Line count -- >> 4

Line count -- >> 5

odd

and so on ....
Why do i get lineCount incremented two times ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException
{
    final File file = new File("C:\\textstr.txt");
    final Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(file);
    int lineCount = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (fileRead.hasNextLine())
    {
        lineCount++;
        i = lineCount % 2;
        final String str = fileRead.nextLine();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Line count -- >> " + lineCount);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    fileRead.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing linecount is outside of your condition checking for the number being odd, so you will get that output twice for every odd line. You're also not going to get each odd line as you're only reading to the next line when linecount is odd

You want something along the lines of:

```
String line = fileRead.nextLine();
if(i == 1){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: plus i get printed all lines, not just odd lines, when i remove the if, the line count is ok

Answer (score 0):

Write the println statement in the if condition.